# Mapping unknown data to a object (typescript)

Tags: mapping, config

I have an Angular2 application, with data service which provides me some data

```
    readProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._projectenUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <Project[]>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('Projects: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

What I need is a config function to map this unknown data to this object:

```
 export class Project {

  Id: string; //TODO, Guid
  Name: string;
  Description: string;
  CustomerId: string; //TODO, Guid
  LastModifiedDate: string;
  LastModifiedBy: string;
  Permission: string;
```

It needs to be generic, so I don't have any information about the data given by the readProjects fucntion.

I tried looking for a similar solution, but most examples use the information about the returned data, e.g. knowing that the data contains projects with similar members as the Project model object, which can be mapped.

Any tips, links, examples are very welcome!